# Open a location in Bing Maps 3D

Tags: bing-maps, 3d

Does anyone know how I can link to a location in Bing Maps and have it open in 3D mode?

A link formatted like this:

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?lvl=15&cp=37.9609257054894~-87.3786394334287

will open that location using their standard 2D map.  Is there anything I can add in to have it open in 3D instead?

Thanks,
Seth

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add the parameters

```
&lvl=15&tlt=-90&alt=3224.73867795803&dir=0&cam=37.9607208577646~-87.3786394334287
```

&lvl=15 = zoom level

&tlt=-90 = tilt

&alt=3224' = altitude

&dir=0 = direction (0 is North)

&cam= camera position lat/lng

Full link (try it)

http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&cp=37.96072085776606~-87.3786394334287&lvl=15&tlt=-90&alt=3224.73867795803&dir=0&cam=37.9607208577646~-87.3786394334287

**Please note:** will only be active 3D view when the Virtual Earth Plugin (Bing Maps 3D now) is installed (IE only)
http://www.bing.com/maps/Help/VE3DInstall/

Hybrid and Direction options
http://www.bing.com/maps/default.aspx?v=2&cp=37.95860908056448~-87.37850329842601&lvl=17&sty=h&tlt=-19.2654529200015&alt=1119.90906599071&dir=101.685687616947&cam=37.9633254924612~-87.4073027434547

additional for hybrid and looking east

&sty=h =hybrid mode

&dir=101 =direction east

Comment: Looks great!  Is there an attribute to have the aerial imagery active?

Comment: added &sty=h see link above